# Fast escaping/deparsing of character vectors in R

Tags: regex, r, escaping, gsub

To encode strings in json, several reserved characters need to be escaped with a backslash, and each string needs to be wrapped in double quotes. Currently the `jsonlite` package implements this using the `deparse` function in base R:

```
deparse_vector <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x))
  vapply(x, deparse, character(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
```

This does the trick:

```
test <- c("line\nline", "foo\\bar", "I said: \"hi!\"")
cat(deparse_vector(test))
```

However `deparse` turns out to be slow for large vectors. An alternative implementation is to `gsub` each character individually:

```
deparse_vector2 <- function(x) {
  stopifnot(is.character(x))
  if(!length(x)) return(x)
  x <- gsub("\\", "\\\\", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\"", "\\\"", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\n", "\\n", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\r", "\\r", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\t", "\\t", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\b", "\\b", x, fixed=TRUE)
  x <- gsub("\f", "\\f", x, fixed=TRUE)
  paste0("\"", x, "\"")
}
```

This is a bit faster, but not much and a bit ugly too. What would be a better way to do this? (preferably without additional dependencies)

This [script](https://gist.github.com/jeroenooms/498223c20d7e0416c169) can be used to compare the implementations:

```
> system.time(out1 <- deparse_vector1(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.517   0.000   6.523 
> system.time(out2 <- deparse_vector2(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.194   0.000   1.194
```

Comment: Can you at least post some timings you've done so we know what "fast enough" would be?

Comment: I added a link to a script to compare implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a faster way to do this with just R code, but I did decide to try my hand at implementing it in C, wrapped in an R function called `deparse_vector3`. It's rough (and I'm far from an expert C programmer) but it seems to work for your examples: https://gist.github.com/wch/e3ec5b20eb712f1b22b2

On my system (Mac, R 3.1.1), `deparse_vector2` is over 20x faster than `deparse_vector`, which is a much bigger difference than the 5x you got in your test.

My `deparse_vector3` function is just 3x faster than `deparse_vector2`. There's probably room for improvement.

```
> system.time(out1 <- deparse_vector1(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.459   0.009   8.470 
> system.time(out2 <- deparse_vector2(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.368   0.007   0.374 
> system.time(out3 <- deparse_vector3(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.120   0.001   0.120
```

I don't think this will correctly handle non-ASCII character encodings, though. Here's an example of how encodings are handled in the R source: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bfe73ecd848198cb9b68427cec7e70c40f96bd72/src/main/grep.c#L588-L630

Edit: This seems to handle UTF-8 OK, though it's possible I'm missing something in my testing.

Comment: I tried to plug this in `jsonlite`, and it seems to work but it is giving segfaults in R after using it for a while...

Comment: I think `val = mkChar(newstr)` needs to be val = PROTECT(mkChar(newstr));` (plus unprotect after `Free()`).

Comment: @Jeroen, does it work with `PROTECT` added? I saw lots of `mkChar`'s in the R source without `PROTECT`, so I figured that they didn't need to be protected, but I could have been wrong about that.

Comment: I found the problem - I wasn't allocating enough memory for the terminating `\0` in the string. Allocating one more byte seems to fix it. I've updated the gist.

Comment: Hey @wch I think the line numbers have fallen out of date. I took a guess at a range of lines that would be reasonable to reference & added a fixed commit ref to the URL. Thanks as always for maintaining the GH mirror

Answer (score 7):

Here's a C++ version of Winston's code. It's quite a lot simpler because you can efficiently grow `std::string`s. It's also less likely to crash because Rcpp takes care of memory management for you.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string escape_one(std::string x) {
  std::string out = "\"";

  int n = x.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    char cur = x[i];

    switch(cur) {
      case '\\': out += "\\\\"; break;
      case '"':  out += "\\\""; break;
      case '\n': out += "\\n";  break;
      case '\r': out += "\\r";  break;
      case '\t': out += "\\t";  break;
      case '\b': out += "\\b";  break;
      case '\f': out += "\\f";  break;
      default:     out += cur;
    }
  }

  out += '"';

  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector escape_chars(CharacterVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  CharacterVector out(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    String cur = x[i];
    out[i] = escape_one(cur);
  }

  return out;
}
```

On your benchmark, `deparse_vector2(strings)` takes 0.8s, and `escape_chars(strings)` takes 0.165s.

Comment: Small suggestion: use `out.reserve(n)` to pre-allocate some memory for output in `escape_one`, to avoid reallocations (we know `out` is at least as big as `x`).

Comment: @KevinUshey I actually tried that elsewhere - it improves performance by about 10%

Answer (score 4):

You can also try `stri_escape_unicode` from the `stringi` package (although you preferred a solution without additional dependencies but I think it could be useful for future readers too) which about 3 times faster than `deparse_vector2` and about 7 times faster than `deparse_vector`

```
require(stringi)
```

Defining the function

```
deparse_vector3 <- function(x){
  paste0("\"",stri_escape_unicode(x), "\"")
}
```

Checking that all functions give smae result

```
all.equal(deparse_vector2(test), deparse_vector3(test))
## [1] TRUE
all.equal(deparse_vector(test), deparse_vector3(test))
## [1] TRUE
```

Some benchmarks

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(deparse_vector(test), 
               deparse_vector2(test),
               deparse_vector3(test), times = 1000L)

# Unit: microseconds
#                  expr    min      lq  median      uq      max neval
#  deparse_vector(test) 98.548 102.654 104.707 111.380 2500.653  1000
# deparse_vector2(test) 43.114  46.707  48.761  51.327  401.377  1000
# deparse_vector3(test) 14.885  16.938  18.991  20.018  240.211  1000 <-- Clear winner
```

Answer (score 3):

One more stab at this problem that takes advantage of a couple facts.

Given a string `x` with length `n`, we know the output string will be at least length `x`, and at most `2 * x`. We can take advantage of this to ensure we only allocate memory once, rather than rely on containers that grow (albeit efficiently).

Note that I make use of C++11's `shared_ptr` here, since I am doing ugly things with raw memory (and want to ensure it gets cleaned up automatically). This also allows me to avoid the initial pass wherein I attempt to count matches, but also forces me to over-allocate a bit excessively (the case wherein every single character must be escaped will be rare).

It would be relatively easy to adapt this to a pure C solution, I think, but would be trickier to ensure memory is properly cleaned up.

```
#include <memory>
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void escape_one_fill(CharacterVector const& x, int i, CharacterVector& output) {

  auto xi = CHAR(STRING_ELT(x, i));
  int n = strlen(xi);

  // Over-allocate memory -- we know that in the worst case the output
  // string is 2x the length of x (plus 1 for \0)
  auto out = std::make_shared<char*>(new char[n * 2 + 1]);

  int counter = 0;
  (*out)[counter++] = '"';

  #define HANDLE_CASE(X, Y) \
    case X: \
      (*out)[counter++] = '\\'; \
      (*out)[counter++] = Y; \
      break;

  for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    switch (xi[j]) {
      HANDLE_CASE('\\', '\\');
      HANDLE_CASE('"', '"');
      HANDLE_CASE('\n', 'n');
      HANDLE_CASE('\r', 'r');
      HANDLE_CASE('\t', 't');
      HANDLE_CASE('\b', 'b');
      HANDLE_CASE('\f', 'f');
      default: (*out)[counter++] = xi[j];
    }
  }

  (*out)[counter++] = '"';

  // Set a NUL so that Rf_mkChar does what it should
  (*out)[counter++] = '\0';
  SET_STRING_ELT(output, i, Rf_mkChar(*out));

}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector escape_chars_with_fill(CharacterVector x) {
  int n = x.size();
  CharacterVector out(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    escape_one_fill(x, i, out);
  }

  return out;
}
```

Benchmarking this, I get (just comparing to Hadley's impl):

```
> mychars <- c(letters, " ", '"', "\\", "\t", "\n", "\r", "'", "/", "#", "$");

> createstring <- function(length){
+   paste(mychars[ceiling(runif(length, 0, length(mychars)))], collapse="")
+ }

> strings <- vapply(rep(1000, 10000), createstring, character(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)

> system.time(escape_chars(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.14    0.00    0.14 

> system.time(escape_chars_with_fill(strings))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.080   0.001   0.081 

> identical(escape_chars(strings), escape_chars_with_fill(strings))
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: (+1), thoogh I don't think `system.time` is the correct way to compare methods, especially when there such a small difference